# krusader - single queue instead of multiple queues

Tags: ubuntu, kde, kubuntu

I need to copy a whole bunch of files from various directories onto an external drive.

I thought Krusader might be the best tool for this job.

As I select and copy different files, a new queue keeps being opened. On Mechanical drives this is not ideal as it causes the hard drive heads to thrash.

How do I get a single queue in Krusader?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you copy, move, pack or unpack files with Krusader, the confirmation dialog will show a button labeled "F2 Queue". Press the button or F2 to add the current job to the queue manager.

A quick way to copy files with the queue manager is pressing F5 then F2. To move files, F6 then F2.

Comment: You may use Shift+F5 in order to have a single key. In case you prefer the queue most of the times, you may also swap F5/Shift+F5 behavior. in "Settings/Configure shortcuts" and set F5 to CopyByQueue and Shift+F5 to plain copy.

Needless to say the same stands for F6/Move.

Comment: There is also a new feature in Krusader 2.6 (I think): under "Settings/Job Queue Mode", enabling that will put all jobs in the queue by default. Really handy!

Comment: sad, but there is no more confirmation dialog, since probably spring 2017 (at least in version 17.04 of Ubuntu)

Comment: No, there's still is (unless perhaps you disable it in settings).

Comment: How in the world do I open the queue window? I want to see the queue status and progress.

Comment: @SyaifulNizamYahya There's no window in version 2.6+, but a toolbar: "Settings/Toolbars/Show Job Toolbar".